# How do I find the mid time between two times in R, sometimes overnight, sometimes same day, but I have no date?

Tags: r

I would like to find the mid time between two times in column SLQ300 (sleep time) and SLQ310 (wake up time) in my data frame of 6000 participants.
Added: I have already the duration in column SLD012. So if we could add half of the duration to the sleep time, it would be great.

Eg. in the first row it should be the midpoint between 23:00 and 07:00, which is 03:00.

And in the 9th row, it should be between 01:00 and 06:00, which is 03:30.

Thank you in advance!

[Data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGenf.png)

Comment: Please don't provide an image of code or data, you're expecting us to transcribe data that you already have in an easy-to-use format. Just post the output from `dput(.)`, or build the data programmatically with `data.frame(.)` (and give us the code, not just the output). https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
time2num <- function(x) {
  vapply(strsplit(x, ':'), function(y) sum(as.numeric(y) * c(60, 1)),
         numeric(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}

# sample data
dat <- data.frame(id=1:2, tm1=c("23:00","01:00"), tm2=c("07:00","06:00"))

# the code
dat[,c("tm1n","tm2n")] <- lapply(dat[,c("tm1","tm2")], time2num)
dat
#   id   tm1   tm2 tm1n tm2n
# 1  1 23:00 07:00 1380  420
# 2  2 01:00 06:00   60  360
with(dat, ifelse(tm1n > tm2n, 24*60, 0) + tm2n - tm1n)
# [1] 480 300   ### minutes
```

Or you can use modulus:

```r
with(dat, tm2n - tm1n) %% (12*60)
```

(though I haven't tested it in all sorts of combinations).

And the mid time:

```r
format(as.POSIXct(paste(Sys.Date(), dat$tm1)) +
         60*with(dat, ifelse(tm1n > tm2n, 24*60, 0) + tm2n - tm1n)/2,
       format="%H:%M")
# [1] "03:00" "03:30"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer gives me the duration in minutes between the two times.
But I'm actually looking for the mid time. Eg. the mid time between 23:00 and 07:00 should be 03:00.