# if else statement with between condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to pass an if-else statement in R where I am looking at the time in the column. I want to create a column called "after hours" where I will look at the time from another column. If the time falls between 8am and 5pm then it is not after hours but if it falls after 5pm and before 8 am then it is after hours.

my table looks something like this

| date | time |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 7:34 AM |
| 01/02/2022 | 14:54 PM |
| 01/03/2022 | 17:59 PM |

And when I create the "after hours" column it should look something like this

| date | time | after hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2022 | 7:34 AM | Yes |
| 01/02/2022 | 14:54 PM | No |
| 01/03/2022 | 17:59 PM | Yes |

I tried this if else statement but I keep getting an error

dplyr::mutate(`intake_received_after_hours`=ifelse(`intake_time`=between("17:01" & "7:59")), yes, no)

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `intake_received_after_hours`.
x unused argument (intake_time = between("17:01" & "7:59"))
i Input `intake_received_after_hours` is `ifelse(intake_time = between("17:01" & "7:59"))`.

Comment: It will be easier to help you with your specific question if you include a code sample to create your sample data.

In any case, the `between` function in R that takes a from and to parameter and returns a boolean should cover what you need.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and where you fail? It would also be nice if you gave your examples in an easy-to-paste manner. More info on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Your first two columns are strings, they have nothing to do with dates or times. If you want numeric "between" comparisons, then you need to convert into something number-like. In this case, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67548644/3358272 for one way to convert time-like strings into number-like things (without dates). (One could also use the `lubridate` package for similar purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `hm` from `lubridate` and some logical conditioning.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  mutate('after hours'=ifelse(
    hm(time) > hm("8:00") & 
    hm(time) < hm("17:00"), "No", "Yes"))
        date     time after hours
1 01/01/2022  7:34 AM         Yes
2 01/02/2022 14:54 PM          No
3 01/03/2022 17:59 PM         Yes
```